# How do I auto update my cx_freeze application in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, auto-update

I created my own app but when I change my script I need to delete my old exe files and then rebuild it.
Is there a way to make updates, only to my exe file and not to the data files?
**python 3.7**